# FirebaseMessagingService is never called when app is installed

Tags: android, push-notification, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I just added FCM to my existing app and it looks like it's not being FirebaseMessagingService is not being called at all.

I had created a POC for the same and it worked fine. On installing the app onNewToken callback was called and onMessageReceived was called when the app was in the foreground.

But in my existing project, it does not seem to work. Please note that my project already supports firebase remote config

google-services.json file was already been downloaded and placed under app dir.

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<service
        android:name=".MyFirebaseMessaging"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

MyFirebaseMessaging.java

```
public class MyFirebaseMessaging extends FirebaseMessagingService {
private final String TAG = MyFirebaseMessaging.class.getSimpleName();
public final static String channel1ID = "channel1ID";
public final static String channel1Name = "channel1Name";

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    Log.i(TAG, "<<notification>> onMessageReceived");
    if (remoteMessage == null) {
        return;
    }
    if (remoteMessage.getData() != null && remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
        Map<String, String> data = remoteMessage.getData();
        String body = data.get("body");
        String title = data.get("title");
        generateNotification(title, body);
    } else if(remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
        RemoteMessage.Notification notification = remoteMessage.getNotification();
        String title = notification.getTitle();
        String body = notification.getBody();
        generateNotification(title, body);
    }
}

private void generateNotification(String title, String body) {
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        NotificationChannel channel1 = new NotificationChannel(channel1ID, channel1Name,
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);

        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel1);
    }

    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.my_large_icon);

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channel1ID)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.my_icon)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(body)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
            .setLargeIcon(bitmap)
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle().bigPicture(bitmap).bigLargeIcon(null));

    notificationManager.notify(0, builder.build());

}

@Override
public void onNewToken(String s) {
    super.onNewToken(s);
    Log.i(TAG, "<<notification>> onNewToken: " + s);
}
}
```

build.gradle - app

```
dependencies {
   ...
  implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.0'
  implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:19.0.1'
  ...
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

build.gradle - project

```
 dependencies {
   ...
   classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
   ...
 }
```

Comment: could you try with a downgraded messaging? like 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.1.0'

Comment: do u use Firebase console to send messages ?

Comment: @JolsonDaCosta i used firebase console and also postman to send data payload. both r not working

Comment: @majuran will try. but its working fine in my poc project

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with these versions. Because in my app it is working fine.

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.8'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.6.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

Found out the problem. Issue was my project was using deprecated FirebaseInstanceIdService. Removing them from my manifest file worked

```
<receiver
        android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdInternalReceiver"
        tools:node="remove" />
    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver"
        tools:node="remove" />

    <service
        android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService"
        tools:node="remove" />
```